# php mysql row dependencies check

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL structure is:

```
id Ergebnis gewinn multi
1  gewonnen 2      8550
2  verloren 0      8550
3  gewonnen 2      6990
4  gewonnen 5      6990
5  gewonnen 12     1443
6  verloren 0      2201
```

I need to get values from `gewinn` counted together where multi is same, but only when `ergebnis == gewonnen` (for all with same multi-value), if one or all `ergebnis = verloren` the total `multi == verloren`. so for this example the correct output will be:

```
8550 == verloren / 0
6990 == gewonnen / 7
1443 == gewonnen / 12
2201 == verloren / 0
```

Comment: What happened to 8550 gewonnen?

Comment: Also the result table appears to be redundant. 0 always equals 'lose'

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a31e/3

Comment: works like charm, thanks

Comment: one issue. if u change win & lose from ur fiddle on the 8550 the fiddle results in "win", but in case if any lose the total 8550 should be lose

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_increment primary key
, result varchar(12)
, winnings int
, multi int
);

insert into my_table values
(1  ,'win', 2    ,  8550),
(2  ,'lose', 0    ,  8550),
(3  ,'win', 2    ,  6990),
(4  ,'win', 5     , 6990),
(5  ,'win', 12    , 1443),
(6 , 'lose', 0    ,  2201);

select x.result
     , sum(z.winnings) total
     , x.multi
  from my_table x
  join 
     ( SELECT MULTI
            , MAX(ID) max_id
         FROM MY_table
        group 
           by multi
     ) y
    on y.multi = x.multi
   and y.max_id = x.id
  join my_table z
    on z.multi = x.multi
   and z.result = x.result
 group
    by x.multi, x.result;
+--------+-------+-------+
| result | total | multi |
+--------+-------+-------+
| win    |    12 |  1443 |
| lose   |     0 |  2201 |
| win    |     7 |  6990 |
| lose   |     0 |  8550 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Fiddle for same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a31e/3

EDIT: A crude extension to this idea - to return lose/0 if a multi incurs any loss...

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.result,a.result) result
     , COALESCE(b.winnings,a.total) total
     , a.multi
  FROM 
     ( 
     select x.result
     , sum(z.winnings) total
     , x.multi
  from my_table x
  join 
     ( SELECT MULTI
            , MAX(ID) max_id
         FROM MY_table
        group 
           by multi
     ) y
    on y.multi = x.multi
   and y.max_id = x.id
  join my_table z
    on z.multi = x.multi
   and z.result = x.result
 group
    by x.multi, x.result
    ) a
  LEFT JOIN my_table b
  ON b.multi = a.multi
  AND b.result = 'lose';
```

Comment: there's no error, but result is not as expected when u change the rows. there has to be a check if multi == lose make complete multi = lose and take next. only if all id's from multi are win then count result

Answer (score 0):

if u change the insert into:

```
insert into my_table values
 (1  ,'lose', 0    ,  8550),
 (2  ,'win', 2    ,  8550),
(3  ,'win', 2    ,  6990),
(4  ,'win', 5     , 6990),
(5  ,'win', 12    , 1443),
(6 , 'lose', 0    ,  2201);
```

the result is for e.g.: 8550 -> win
but should be lose.
in case of any id with same multi == lose the complete multi should be result lose